# How to Create Task Items With Custom List Dataview

Tags: sharepoint-online, application-pages, task-list

I have created 2 custom lists in Sharepoint 2010:

List #1: INTERNAL PROCESSES (fields: Process Title, Reference)

List #2: PROCESS STEPS (fields: Step Title, Step Description, Process Title[lookup of 1 item in previous list], Department Assigned)

I created an action in the display form for list INTERNAL PROCESSES called "Create Instance"; when user clicks on it, it redirects the user to `mypage.aspx?processID={itemID}`
(I couldn't find a way to pass the title instead of the ID in the querystring).

So now I need to accomplish the following in mypage.aspx:

1. Find the item in INTERNAL PROCESSES using the ID received in the querystring. If field Reference is not NULL, ask the user to enter a value for Reference (e.g. if the Reference contains the word "Member", ask the user to enter the Member Name).
2. Get the Process Title from list INTERNAL PROCESSES for the ID received in querystring
3. For each list item in PROCESS STEPS where field Process Title matches Process Title looked up in step#2 , create a new TASK list item with the following values:

   a) TASK Title = Step Title + Value entered in step#1 (if any)

   b) TASK Description = Step Description

   c) TASK Assigned to = Department Assigned

I'd like to avoid using code, if at all possible, because I've never done it. If code is required then please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two "no code" options to do this, but both require some scripting (which to me is code):

1. Have mypage.aspx be an initiation page for a SharePoint Designer workflow. You'd set the initiation values for the workflow in the page, probably using some script to get the value for Reference and pass it into the workflow.
2. Do the whole thing with script, using my SPServices library for the lookups and creating the tasks real time:

   [CodePlex: SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com)

Comment: thank you Marc! option #1 isn't good because workflows cannot have a dynamic number of steps and I need to create a number of tasks that will depend on the number of steps for the selected item in INTERNAL PROCESSES ....option #2 can you be more specific what steps I need to take to achieve the results, where exactly to download, install and insert the scripts...thanks

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the code to solve this. It'll take quite a bit of work and debugging. The construct is specific to your environment, so no one is going to be able to give it to you. Check the SPServices site for examples.